# Error while make for pyotherside

Tags: python-3.x, makefile

I want to install pyotherside for my ubuntu 14.10, so I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/thp/pyotherside.git
cd pyotherside
sudo qmake
```

which succeeds, but when I do:

```
sudo make
```

it says:

```
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /usr/src/pyotherside/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
Project MESSAGE: PYTHON_CONFIG = python3-config
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 3
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out afterwards.

Ubuntu 14.10 has a QT5 already installed, but it is QT5.0 and you should manually change to QT5.4 you installed.

```
sudo home/X/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

This works perfectly.